# Zend: Create action in a specific controller in specific module with command line

Tags: php, zend-framework, module, zend-tool

I want to create a testAction in testController  of testModule with command line. So I go to tesModule directory(cd application/modules/test) and run the following command.

```
zf.sh create action test -c test
```

It created a action in `application/modules/test/controllers/testController.php` but it created testAction's **test.phtml** file in `application/views/scripts/test/` folder. But I think it should be in same module folder like this: `application/modules/test/views/scripts/test/` folder.

What command should I use that will create action and its phtml file in same module folder.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

zf.sh create test test 1 test